# a specific api that search imagen in ruby didn t work to me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api-design, api-doc

i am trying get the response of this api:
[here is some documentation of the api](http://contextualwebsearch.com/freeapi) 
 so when i try to call the api, the console give me the following menssage:

```
web_1       | #<Unirest::HttpResponse:0x000055ac03684818 @code=200,@headers={:d
ate=>"Sat, 23 Jun 2018 06:17:30 GMT", :server=>"Microsoft-IIS/8.5", :cache_contr
ol=>"no-cache", :pragma=>"no-cache", :content_length=>"29", :content_type=>"appl
ication/json; charset=utf-8", :expires=>"-1", :x_aspnet_version=>"4.0.30319", :x
_powered_by=>"ASP.NET"}, @raw_body=<RestClient::Response 200 "{\"_type\":\"i..."
>, @body={"_type"=>"images", "value"=>[]}>
```

but if you see the "value" where the url of the imagens must be, it is empty and i don t know why, this is my code:

```
require 'json'
require 'unirest'
response = Unirest.get "http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true"
puts response.inspect
```

and the rare of all of this, it is that if you go to this page:
http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true you will find the json with all the information that i am searching.

Comment: it's working i got below response `response.raw_body
 => "{\"_type\":\"images\",\"value\":[{\"url\":\"https://images.thestar.com/wueERUqdCWo43wnFg8CH82bvfUk=/1200x835/smart/filters:cb(1529726400000)/https://www.thestar.com/content/dam/thestar/news/world/2018/06/22/donald-trump-says-north-korea-still-poses-an-extraordinary-threat/nkorea_threat.jpg\",\"height\":835,\"width\":1200}]}" `

Comment: why to you work?i do the same of you and it don t work see that i put the same of you and the response is:

       ´web_1       | {"_type":"images","value":[]}´

and i did the same of you:

response = Unirest.get "http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true"
  puts response.raw_body

Comment: what is the op of `curl "http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true"`

Comment: sorry for the past comment i didn t know how write code, what is "op"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rest-client`

```
require 'net/http' 
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'
res = RestClient.get("http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true")
body = JSON.parse(res, { symbolize_names: true })
puts body[:value]
```

Also `Unirest` works fine

```
require 'json'
require 'unirest'
response = Unirest.get "http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true"
puts response.body["value"]
```

Comment: this work perfect, but i don t know why, can you give the reason pls :D, in resume if you think is so long please

Comment: i am not sure, but it works just tested unirest also, post updated.

Comment: `puts "nueva investigacion"`(enter)

  `response = Unirest.get "http://contextualwebsearch.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?q=donald%20trump&count=10&autoCorrect=true"`(enter)

  `puts response.body["value"].inspect`
and the result was:
`web_1       | nueva investigacion`

`web_1       | []`

Comment: @mrpepo877 make sure unirest gem is installed or probably you have exceeded limits of api calls. But yr code works fine on my side.

Comment: what is it y´r?

Comment: in the Gemfile.lock i have DEPENDENCIES `unirest`, in my Gemfile i have `gem 'unirest'` and if a use the command `gem query --local` the result show me `unirest (1.0.8)`

Comment: @mrpepo877 not sure what can be the issue, use `rest-client` its also fast and light.